# Connect Heroku Application with my GoDaddy Domain

Tags: heroku, dns, appdomain, cname

I've set up a application on Heroku and have also purchased a domain from GoDaddy.

I searched on Google how to connect my domain to Heroku and I also read the Heroku documentation but I am not able to connect it with my domain.

I am a beginner and have found I need to add cname or domain may be but I don't know how to do it. How can I connect my domain with the heroku app? I need to add DNS on my domain but how to add it?

Please let me know very very basic and detail step by step procedure to connect my domain with the Heroku app please.

Comment: Well you google right ? then .......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible duplicate.. As per the user request we do ...

There are 2 steps you need to perform,

Add the custom domains addon and add the domain your going to use, eg www.mywebsite.com to your application, Running below command to perform this task

> heroku domains:add www.example.com

Go to your domain registrar control panel and set www.mywebsite.com to be a CNAME entry to yourapp.herokuapp.com assuming you are using the CEDAR stack.

just put www in value and target is your heroku app like yourname.herokuapp.com

Answer (score 2):

Heroku provides detailed instructions in the [Custom Domains](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains) support page.