# Use GoDaddy domain with Heroku app via CNAME

Tags: heroku, dns

I have been trying to follow these instructions (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains) and similar posts ([How to configure heroku application DNS to Godaddy Domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170664/how-to-configure-heroku-application-dns-to-godaddy-domain), [Connect Heroku Application with my GoDaddy Domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24703155/connect-heroku-application-with-my-godaddy-domain)). Unfortunately, these instructions simply do not work for me. When I followed them, including forwarding my naked domain to a www CNAME record, I would get a redirect loop error when browsing to my custom domain.

When I contacted GoDaddy, they suggested that, instead of a CNAME record, I forward my domain to my app using masking, which I did following these instructions (https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/422/manually-forwarding-or-masking-your-domain-name?locale=en). This is working, but I'd still much rather use a CNAME record because my current solution apparently prevents my page titles and favicon from coming through.

How can I use a GoDaddy domain name with my Heroku app via a CNAME record? I'm very new to DNS configuration, so any suggestions/questions/comments would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy. Move your domain from GoDaddy to dnsimple.com.

Dnsimple supports apex domain aliasing to heroku with a 1-click service: https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/domain-apex-heroku/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was still hoping for a solution that didn't require moving my domain name, but I suppose I may end up having to do that.

Comment: It's been several months, but I'm accepting this answer because I did end up transferring my domain name. I don't think it's possible to do what I wanted to do with GoDaddy and Heroku.

Answer (score 3):

To connect your heroku hosting to godaddy,

You have to open your godaddy account and in the DNS Management page add in the cname the host: www and in the point to: your heroku url And in the heroku page in the settings add three domains:

```
1 *.xxx.com 
2: xxx.com
3. www.xxx.com
```

This should work :) Check this video to make it easier for you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kKGSGT7mSnQ&feature=youtu.be